# Can't resolve a Locale

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, locale

I have a problem with Locale's. I'm trying to do a simple thing where I can choose english or german.
So I have two property files called
       messages_en and
       messages_de.
So far these files have a single line:

```
        contactbook = Contact Book
```

and

```
        contactbook = Adressbuch
```

respectively.

Now in my JSP view I have this :

```
        <spring:message code="contactbook"/>
```

The idea is that the message in the view changes depending on which locale we're using. Now the locale itself should be changed with this line:

```
    <a href="?language=en">English</a>|<a href="?language=de">German</a>
```

If I remove the  everything works great but of course it's not locale specified. So the rest of the view is good.

In my dispatcher-servlet.xml file I have this:

```
<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="language" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" >
    <property name="interceptors">
       <list>
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
       </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Again, without it everything works well. There's something wrong with my understanding here. The localeChangeInterceptor stops any change done to the locale and the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping does what? I keep on looking at my controller and wondering should I add something to it but it seems to me that all these lines in the dispatcher should be enough.

The exception I get is

```
 No message found under code 'contactbook' for locale 'en'
```

Despite a myriad of examples out there I keep on failing to understand or resolve the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is your `MessageSource` configuration, also if you are using `<mvc:annotation-driven />` you must use `<mvc:interceptors />` to register the interceptor and not define additional `HandlerMapping`s.

Comment: yeah, it seems to me you are following some out of date tutorial. in current code, use the mvc namespace or JavaConfig. See: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-interceptors

Answer (score 2):

You need configure a ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource. 
look at java doc [Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html).

Example.

```
     <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
                    <!--classpath of your messages-->
                <property name="basename" value="classpath:/i18n/messages" />
                <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true" />
                <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need working example of JavaConfig SpringMVC app I can help you with my code. I've been developing the same kind of simple app. Here is configuration of SpringMVC:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean(name = "viewResolver")
public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    resolver.setPrefix("/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");

    return resolver;
}

@Bean(name = "messageSource")
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource getReloadableResourceBundle(){
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource resourceBundle = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    resourceBundle.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    resourceBundle.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

    return resourceBundle;
}

@Bean(name = "localeResolver")
public SessionLocaleResolver getSessionLocaleResolver(){
    SessionLocaleResolver resolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);

    return resolver;
}

@Bean(name = "localeChangeInterceptor")
public LocaleChangeInterceptor getLocaleChangeInterceptor(){
    LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    interceptor.setParamName("language");

    return interceptor;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/css*").addResourceLocations("/resources/css/");
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(getLocaleChangeInterceptor());
}
}
```

Also if it won't solve your problem and your config will be working fine, just try to put line spacer before the very first message in every .message file in your message bundle. (It helped me once when I've been getting the same exception you got and I don't know why, just saying ;P )